# PHP/WordPress: override page_id in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and currently the code it set to create titles based on the page title.  The titles are: Interior House Painting, Exterior House Painting and Commercial Painting.  I would like to override the titles to remove the word "house".  This is the code currently:

```
<?php
// interior_painting: 18
// exterior_painting: 25
// other services: 36
$page_ids = array(18, 25, 36);
$images = array('servicesInterior.jpg', 'servicesExterior.jpg', 'servicesOther.jpg');
foreach ($page_ids as $key => $page_id) {
    $page_post = get_post($page_id);
    $page_custom_key = 'home_page_info';
    $page_link = $page_post->post_name;
    $li_class = $page_id == 36 ? 'noMargin' : '';
    $title = $page_id == 18 ? 'Interior Painting' : $page_post->post_title . " ";
    $title = $page_id == 36 ? 'Commercial Projects' : $page_post->post_title . " ";
    $title = $page_id == 25 ? 'Exterior Painting' : $page_post->post_title . " ";


    echo '<li class="' . $li_class . '"> <a href="' . $page_link . '">';
    echo '<img class="alignright size-full wp-image-349" title="servicesInterior" src="/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/' . $images[$key] . '" alt="" width="200" height="95" /></a>';
    echo '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>';
    echo get_post_meta($page_id, $page_custom_key, true);
    echo '<a class="btn-find-more" href="' . $page_post->post_name . '">FIND OUT MORE</a></li>';
}

?>
```

The output is this: Interior House Painting, Exterior Painting, Commercial Painting.  How do I get "house" removed from "Interior House Painting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$title = ucwords(trim(strtolower(str_replace('house', '', $page_post->post_title))));
```

Though, I am a little curious as to why you would not prefer to just remove the word from the title altogether.

**ADDITIONALLY:** Somebody else mentioned using preg_replace. That's also entirely possible, but it would be best to do a case-insensitive search:

```
$title = trim(preg_replace('/house/i', '', $page_post->post_title));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `preg_replace('House'|| 'house','',/*Variable Page title is in*/);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the line:

```
echo '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>';
```

With something like this:

```
if (is_page('Interior House Painting')) { echo '<h2>Interior Painting</h2>'; } 
if (is_page('Exterior House Painting')) { echo '<h2>Exterior Painting</h2>'; } 
else { echo '<h2>' . $title. '</h2>'; }
```